# Number of parameters on the general solution of a differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation  :
$c_1$.x'' + $c_2 $.x = 0 .

Being $w=\sqrt{ c_1/c_2 }$ I was told that the general solution can be either
$x(t) =  A.cos(wt + \phi_1 )$         or
$x(t) = C.cos(wt+ \phi_2) + D.cos(wt+\phi_3)$

But the thing is that i was told that for linear ODEs, the number of parameters of the general solution  should be the same number of the order of the ODE.
So, in my case this means two parameters, corresponding to two initial conditions.

So, while i understand $x(t) =  A.cos(wt + \phi_1 )$ being a general solution,  i don't understand the other.
Wouldn't " $x(t) = C.cos(wt+ \phi_2) + D.cos(wt+\phi_3)$ "   require four initial conditions, since it has four parameters ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using $w=\sqrt{ c_2/c_1 }$, the general solution is $$x(t)=A\cos(wt)+B\sin(wt)$$ what can be transformed to $x(t) =  C \cos(wt + \phi_1 )$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $x(t) = C.\cos(wt+ \phi_2) + D.\cos(wt+\phi_3)$ they are only two independant coefficients because the four coefficients $C, D, \phi_2, \phi_3$ are dependant through two relationships.
$$x(t) = C.\cos(\phi_2)\cos(wt)-C.\sin(\phi_2)\sin(wt)+D.\cos(\phi_3)\cos(wt)-D.\sin(\phi_3)\sin(wt) $$
$$x(t) = (C.\cos(\phi_2)+D.\cos(\phi_3) )\cos(wt)-(C.\sin(\phi_2)+D.\sin(\phi_3) )\sin(wt) $$
or :
$$x(t) = A.\cos(wt+\phi_1)=A.\cos(\phi_1)\cos(wt)-A.\sin(\phi_1)\sin(wt)$$
So, the relationships are :

First coefficient :
$$(C.\cos(\phi_2)+D.\cos(\phi_3) )=A.\cos(\phi_1)$$
Second coefficient :
$$(D.\sin(\phi_2)+D.\sin(\phi_3) )=A.\sin(\phi_1)$$

Comment: I'm a bit confused.Let's forget the solution $x(t) = A.cos(\phi_1)$ .        Doesn't $x(t)=C.sin(wt+\phi_1) + D.cos(wt+\phi_2)$" have four independent parameters ?    How are there only two independent parameters ?  Sorry for the dumb confusion, i reckon that it might be a bit hard for you to explain me that

Comment: Do you understand what independant and dependant mean? The two independant functions are $C_1cos(wt)$ and $C_2sin(wt)$. Of course you can write the general solution on an infinity of equivalent forms, with as many parameters as you want, but 2 parameters at least. For example $x(t)=C_1\cos(wt)+C_2\sin(wt)$ or $x(t)=A\cos(wt+\phi_1)$ or $=A\sin(wt+\phi_2)$ or $=C_3\cos(wt)+C_4\sin(wt)+C_5\cos(wt+\phi_5)$ , etc. If they are $n>2$ parameters, they are also $(n-2)$ trigonometric equations which allow to reduce the $n$ parameters to only $2$. As shown in my answer in the case of your example $n=4$

Answer (score 0):

For the ODE:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}x}{\mathrm{d}t^{2}}+\omega^{2}x=0$$

We have the generic solution given by:

$$x(t)=\alpha \sin(\omega t)+\beta \cos(\omega t) \qquad \exists \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$$

We can use trigonometric identities to combine these sine and cosine terms into a single sinusoid with a phase difference, so we have:

$$x(t)=A\sin(\omega t + \phi) \qquad \exists A,\phi\in\mathbb{R}$$

You are right that there need to exist 2 boundary conditions for the problem to be completely specified.

Comment: But is "$\alpha.sin(wt) + \beta.cos(wt)" $ the most general solution ?   Isn't  it "$x(t)=\alpha.sin(wt+\phi_1) + \beta.cos(wt+\phi_2)$" the most general one ?

Comment: You can see that the former is the most general solution as we note that in general we can write: $$\sin(\omega t + \phi) = \sin(\phi)\cos(\omega t) + \cos(\phi)\sin(\omega t)$$ But the $\cos(\phi)$ and $\sin(\phi)$ terms just get absorbed into the constants and so the first expression is the most general (and simple).

Answer (score 0):

there are three cases:(1) $c_2/c_1 > 0$ exponential solutions, (2) $c_2/c_1 < 0$ you get periodic solution, and (3) $c2 = 0$ you have a linear solution.

in all three cases you have two arbitrary parameters that will be determined from initial conditions.